# Runtime speed assignment

Tags: python

Good afternoon. I am working on a university assignment. I have a list named list1 with values and I want to input each of the items from this list one by one to a function f1. I wanted to know what would look better for my assignment: using a for loop and then appending each of the items to a new list or using f1(list1[:]).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want, but using a list comprehension or filter should work if you want to apply `f1` to every item in `list1`.

Comment: Honestly, whatever solves the problem looks best.  First make it work, then make it pretty.

Comment: Most important thing is make it work.   list comprehension mentioned above is the most concise way to do it.   A loop is probably a little clearer for beginning programmers.  your code f1(list1[:]) will pass in a copy of the list to f1,  iteration would have to happen in the f1 method.

Comment: How would `f1(list1[:])` even make sense? That doesn't apply `f1` to every element in the list, accumulating the result.

Comment: `list2 = list(map(f1, list1))` ? https://realpython.com/python-map-function/